# Use regular expressions in javascript to manage source files

Tags: javascript, regex, three.js

I am making my first steps coding with JavaScript and also playing with a webgl library called Three.js.

After see some tutorials and make some experiments I finally made this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15814455/Monogram.html.

As you can see in my code, the object reflects randomly a group of 6 images that I have in a folder of 13 images.

```
    var numberOfImages = 13, images = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
        images.push('sources/instagram/image' + i + ".jpg");
    }

    var urls = images.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
    var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
    reflectionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
```

The thing is that each time I upload an Instagram picture, it will be saved in that folder called instagram.

Now my problem is that, if I upload for example, 10 images to the folder I have to change this line of code: `var numberOfImages = 13` to this `var numberOfImages = 23`.

So I am looking for a way to modify my code and not to set a limit of number of images. So I could upload images in the folder and then automatically see them in my 3d object.

I've been reading on internet and I found that I can use something called regular expressions in my code to solve this problem.

I would like to know if using regular expressions is a real solution. Is it worth to learn regular expressions to solve this problem?

Do you have some suggestion? There is another solution? Maybe its something simple and I should write a different line of code, but if it's something more complicated and I should learn some language I would like to learn the right language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you are going to be programming at length in pretty much any language, it will be worth knowing regular expressions and how/when to use them so it's will be useful to learn them.

If this was a client/server problem where you controlled the server, the usual way to solve this problem is that the server would scan the file system on the server and it would tell the client how many images to prepare for.

If you have to solve this entirely on the client, then you can't directly scan the file system from the client, but you can request increasing file numbers and you can see (asynchronously) when you stop getting successful loading of images.  This is not particularly easy to code because the response will be asynchronous, but it could be done.

Here's a scheme for preloading images and finding out where they stopped preloading successfully:

```
function preloadImages(srcs, callback) {
    var img, imgs = [];
    var remaining = srcs.length;
    var failed = [];

    function checkDone() {
        --remaining;
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            callback(failed);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = checkDone;
        img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
            failed.push(this.src);
            checkDone();
        }
        img.src = srcs[i];
        imgs.push(img);
    }
}

var maxNumberOfImages = 30, images = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfImages; i++) {
    images.push('sources/instagram/image' + i + ".jpg");
}

preloadImges(images, function(failed) {
    var regex = /(\d+)\.jpg$/;
    var nums = failed.map(function(item) {
        var matches = item.match(regex);
        return parseInt(matches[1], 10);
    }).sort();
    var numImages = nums[0];
    // now you know how many good images there are
    // put your code here to use that knowledge
});
```

Note: This does use a regular expression to parse the image number out of a URL.

It would be possible to code this without a preset limit, but it would be more work.  You'd probably request images 10 at a time and if you didn't get any errors, then request the next block of 10 until you found the first failure.

Comment: Thank you very much @jfriend00 your info is really helpful. So I understand that the simple way to solve this problem is using client/server. So the server would scan the file system on and it would tell the client how many images to prepare for. But which is the method to make this? Sorry for the question but I am learning...